# Motivation for the norm in $W^{s,p}(\Omega )$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ a bounded domain with good condition. In the fractional Sobolev space, 
$$W^{s,p}(\Omega )=\left\{u\in L^p(\Omega )\;\Bigg|\; \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{\frac{n}{p}+s}}\in L^p(\Omega \times \Omega )\right\},$$
and we give to this space the norm
$$\|u\|_{W^{1,s}(\Omega )}=\left(\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega )}^p+[u]_{W^{s,p}(\Omega )}^p\right)^{1/p},$$
where $$[u]_{W^{s,p}(\Omega )}=\left(\iint_{\Omega \times \Omega }\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{n+sp}}dxdy\right)^{1/p}.$$

> **Question**
>   What is the motivation for $[u]_{W^{s,p}(\Omega )}$ ? Why such an expression ? And if $s=1$ (or maybe $s\to 1$), do we have that $$\lim_{s\to 1}\ [u]_{W^{s,p}(\Omega )}^p=\sum_{i=1}^n\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right\|^p_{L^p(\Omega )}\ \ ?$$
>   If not, I don't understand where would come from $[u]_{W^{s,p}(\Omega )}$.

Comment: The inner part of $[u]_{W^{s,p}}$ is the $\tfrac{n}{p}+s$-sth Hölder seminorm $[u]_{C^{0,n/p+s}}$ of $u$, see Evans p.254. Maybe you get some further insights from Morrey's inequality and the embeddings from Sobolev to Hölder spaces.

Comment: @MarvinF: thanks a lot for this information. I'll check it :-)

Comment: Or more exactly, the *supremum* of the inner part is the Hölder seminorm; so $W^{s,p}$ is what you get by replacing all supremums in the $C^{s,n/p}$ norm with $L^p$ integrals.

Comment: it seems like you disagree with my answer

Answer (score 1):

Originally, the  space $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$   as you defined is a **[real interpolation space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space)**  between $L^p(\Omega)$ and $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ 
this usually holds true whenever $\Omega $ is an extension domain.
for more details check [this valuable lecture note](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwia-KGhyITYAhXEL1AKHWtQAeYQFgg7MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.dmi.unipr.it%2Falessandra.lunardi%2FLectureNotes%2FSNS1999.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0A9imU9ACp7IevzfYwGbpz) at page 12 Example 1.1.8 therein you find how exactly $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ can be constructed from $L^p(\Omega)$ and $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ via real interpolation method.

> For the second question the answer is  **NO and Yes**

NO Because in fact for any non-trivial smooth function one always has

$$\lim_{s\to1} [u]_{W^{s,p}(\Omega )} =\infty$$

**But Yes** there is a convergence: In other to rectify this anomalous one the factor $(1-s)^{1/p}$ to annihilate the singularity at $s=1$ namely we have the following result from [Bourgain-Brezis-Mironescu](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLv-aBrpPYAhXFJVAKHUvBBywQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhal.archives-ouvertes.fr%2Fhal-00747692%2Ffile%2Fanother_look_sobolev_spaces_2000.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1RblvkBCC1clsrQpIo4_N0)

$$\color{red}{\lim_{s\to1} (1-s)\iint_{\Omega \times \Omega }\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{n+sp}}dxdy = K\left\| \nabla u\right\|^p_{L^p(\Omega )} \sim\sum_{i=1}^n\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right\|^p_{L^p(\Omega )}}$$

In addition to your interest we have the following from  [Maz'ya, and Shaposhnikov](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjby_DdspPYAhVJZVAKHR4WDscQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.484.930%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AOvVaw0r-qL8Mk0KqKXs8nM63Uhk) we have

$$\color{red}{\lim_{s\to0} s\iint_{\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n }\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{n+so}}dxdy = K\left\|u\right\|^p_{L^p(\Bbb R^n )} }$$